# Position element at the bottom with prior element filling up height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

First div should fill up remaining height that's left while second div should be positioned at the bottom with it's initial height.

**DEMO:**

```css
.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  border :1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.second {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="first">
I SHOULD FILL WHATS REMAINING AFTER SECOND ONE
</div>
<div class="second">
<div>
I SHOULD BE AT THE BOTTOM FILLING ONLY MY OWN HEIGHT
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. *First div should fill up remaining height that's left* - remaining height from what, where?

Comment: @Chris When second div is positioned at bottom first div should fill the rest of the height ( rest of the height of container ). http://i.imgur.com/l4QdyWP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this would vary from markup to markup, but in your case you can just add this to your `first` element:

`height: 100%;`

This works because of your `flex` display property of the container. A different property on the container would likely require another solution.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hwc85wbz/)

**Full code**

```css
.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  height: 100%;
  border :1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.second {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="first">
I SHOULD FILL WHATS REMAINING AFTER SECOND ONE
</div>
<div class="second">
<div>
I SHOULD BE AT THE BOTTOM FILLING ONLY MY OWN HEIGHT
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make height auto to container class so depend on length of string your height is increase.

```html
<style>
.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
  border :1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.second {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<div class="first">
I SHOULD FILL WHATS REMAINING AFTER SECOND ONE
</div>
<div class="second">
<div>
I SHOULD BE AT THE BOTTOM FILLING ONLY MY OWN HEIGHT
</div>

</div>
```